# type object 'Post' has no attribute 'slug', how to use it from other model

Tags: python, django

I'm in a situation i need to modify my get_absolute_url. I'll explain my situation with the code.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

I have comment in post.html, so for comment get absolute url I want it to be the same page of get absolute url of post. how do I do this?

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": Post.slug})
```

The reason I'm doing it this way is, later I need

```
target_url = self.target_object.get_absolute_url()
```

for comment I need get absolute url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access `self.post.get_absolute_url` like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return self.post.get_absolute_url()
```

However, I would recommend removing `null=True, blank=True` from the `post` definition (unless you plan on having comments that aren't related to any post). This will ensure `self.post` exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": self.post.slug})
```

or better:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.post.get_absolute_url()
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Post.slug
> ```

This references the instance of `CharField` that is in the `Post` class.  It has nothing to do with the particular post that the comment relates to.

Instead try this:

```
self.post.slug
```